# Why does the following code return True?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing an assignment to compile a subset of Pascal and in the initial program there is a line of code like this:

```
if x.tp == y.tp in {Bool, Int}:
    some other code ...
```

This makes me really confused as `x.tp == y.tp` returns a boolean value `True` or `False` and thus `True/False in {Bool, Int}` will always return `False`.

The definition of `Bool` and `Int` is the following:

```
class Int: pass

class Bool: pass
```

Then, I set a breakpoint at that line, and play around in VSCode's debugger:

```
>> x.tp
<class 'ST.Int'>
>> y.tp
<class 'ST.Int'>
>> x.tp == y.tp
True
>> a = (x.tp == y.tp)
None
>> a
True
>> a in {Bool, Int}
False
>> x.tp == y.tp in {Bool, Int}
True       <----------------------- why does it return True?
```

Why does `x.tp == y.tp in {Bool, Int}` return `True` here?

Comment: What are `x.tp` and `y.tp`?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard `x.tp` and `y.tp` are both types. I am not sure if I should post more code since it is too long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parentheses to group the equality comparison:

```
if (x.tp == y.tp) in {Bool, Int}:
```

Your **chained comparison** gets evaluated by Python as:

```
if x.tp == y.tp and y.tp in {Bool, Int}:
```

which yields `True` since `y.tp` is of class `<class 'ST.Int'>` and actually in that set.

From the [Reference Manual on Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be `False`).

Comment: That shouldn't matters as == and in has the same precedence and it will be evaluated from left to right isn't it?

Comment: @Jackddddd `==` gets evaluated, `y.tp in {Bool, Int}` also gets evaluated though (since the equality is `True`) and makes the whole thing `True`, that's how Python deals with chained comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, we're of the assumption that this line of code

```
if x.tp == y.tp in {Bool, Int}:
```

should work (or parsed) like:

```
if (x.tp == y.tp) in {Bool, Int}:
```

But this is **not** the case. According to [this article](http://blog.stirbu.name/2013/07/python-comparison-operators-chaining/), the parsing and then the comparison is done like:

```
if (x.tp == y.tp) and (y.tp in {Bool, Int}) :
```

There's something confusing going on because of not being explicit. Please try to avoid similar situations for the benefit of the code maintainer.

Source: [Python comparison operators chaining](http://blog.stirbu.name/2013/07/python-comparison-operators-chaining/)

Comment: Actualy if you do `True in {bool}` you will get False.

Comment: @Jackddddd Updated the explanation!